# Flutter image picker not working in ios 14 with Mac M1 chip simulator

Tags: flutter, imagepicker, flutter-ios

Image picker appears with list of images , but cannot pick an image from list. I have already added camera permission to plist file. It working in real device with ios 12.6. I am using ios 14 simulator in Mac M1 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading to Xcode 13.1. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Thats bug on m1 silicon you have to downgrade your simulator iOS 13.7
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/110911

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

add this to your info.plist

```
 <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need to upload image</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need to upload image</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need to upload image</string>
```

Comment: `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` seems out of place for an image picker issue. If this is part of the solution, could you explain why?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsmicrophoneusagedescription

Answer (score 0):

**add this line in your info plist file under dict its will help and make sure plist verion 1.0 and now also go in pod file where ios verion should be 10.**

```
 <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app needs access the photo to use for order.</string>
```